# Firebase Performance Monitoring Unable To See Slow Rendering By Screen Data On Dashboard

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

Not able to see slow rendering by screen data on the dashboard with the latest Firebase perf SDK.

**App Level buid.gradle**

```
buildscript {

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}
```

**Module Level buid.gradle**

```
dependencies {

      ................
      ................

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

Added debug and release SHA1 fingerprints then downloaded the latest google-services.json file and put inside app module.

**Also enable auto performance and logging.**

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_performance_collection_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled"
        android:value="true" />
```

I am able to see in logcat. While on Firebase dashboard slow rendering by screen data is not showing. Other data like Network and App Start or Custom trace time is showing in Firbase dashboard.

Comment: I am not getting the data too on dashboard. Any updates on this?

Comment: Remove tag from  AndroidMainfest.xml android:hardwareAccelerated="false", update reflect on dashboard around 12hours.

Comment: Well, I don't have that tag in the manifest, and I don't exactly understand how does that solve the issue. A small explanation could really be helpful.

Comment: In firebase-perf SDK  while having android:hardwareAccelerated="false" in AndroidMainfest.xml give error    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to remove OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener that was never added.  Once you removed that tag OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener initialised perfectly.